# Can you explain the end of this long law sentence for me

Tags: legalese, meaning

This is the sentences. It's really long and complicated and I'm not native English speaker. The end is not clear for me and I don't understand the parts about foreign law and award and etc.

> Slade conceded, However, that if a foreign law were to provide for the
>   plaintiff to serve a notice specifying a sum claimed as damages, and
>   then for a default judgment to be entered for that sum without proof
>   or judicial assessment, such a procedure would usually be considered
>   unobjectionable, provided that, after due allowance had been made for
>   differences between the foreign law and English law in levels of award
>   and in substantive law, the amount of the actual award was not
>   irrational.

Comment: It is long and complicated. Which particular bit[s] of it are you confused about? Saying "all of it" counts as proofreading, which is off-topic.

Comment: probably better suited to SE:Law

Comment: @Mick Thanks. I made it more clear. My problem was with the end of it.

Comment: The whole section is about foreign law; your question includes the term "reward" which is not in the text.  The law site would be better.

Comment: it's funny that this question was asked in Law Stack Exchange, and they referred to this site.  https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/24624/can-you-explain-the-end-of-this-long-law-sentence-for-me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it means that where foreign courts are making an award for damages - they may do so - that process is acceptable - as long as the award is deemed to be 'reasonable' by the English court - presumably within the limits of what is considered 'normal' for such an award, in England.

I am not a lawyer and this is not legal advice - I am a native English speaker. Hope that helps!